# Page fails to upload files

Tags: java, jpa

**I am new to JEE. i have a problem uploading files to a mysql database using JSF 2.2, Primefaces 5.0 on netbeans 8.0.2 and glassfish 4.1. im also using **commons-io-2.4** and **commons-fileupload-1.3** for upload. i have seen similar questions on this site before but none off them seem to address my case.**

**Here is the Exception thrown**

```
     javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.
            at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
            at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
            at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
            at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
            at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
            at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
            at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
            at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:95)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
            at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
            at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
            at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.
            at managed.ClientController.persist(ClientController.java:194)
            at managed.ClientController.createClient(ClientController.java:58)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
            at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
            at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
            at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
            at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
            at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
            ... 41 more
        Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.
            at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:490)
            at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:854)
            at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.UserTransactionImpl.commit(UserTransactionImpl.java:212)
            at managed.ClientController.persist(ClientController.java:191)
            ... 52 more
```

*Here is My Entity Class*

```
    package entity;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import javax.persistence.Basic;
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Lob;
    import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
    import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
    import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    /**
     *
     * @author rue
     */
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "client")
    @XmlRootElement
    @NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Client.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM Client c"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Client.findByEmailAddress", query = "SELECT c FROM Client c WHERE c.emailAddress = :emailAddress"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Client.findByPhoneNumber", query = "SELECT c FROM Client c WHERE c.phoneNumber = :phoneNumber"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Client.findByPhysicalAddress", query = "SELECT c FROM Client c WHERE c.physicalAddress = :physicalAddress"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Client.findByCompanyName", query = "SELECT c FROM Client c WHERE c.companyName = :companyName"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Client.findByServiceOffered", query = "SELECT c FROM Client c WHERE c.serviceOffered = :serviceOffered"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Client.findByLicenseStatus", query = "SELECT c FROM Client c WHERE c.licenseStatus = :licenseStatus")})
    public class Client implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
        @Column(name = "email_address")
        private String emailAddress;
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "phone_number")
        private Integer phoneNumber;
        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, max = 400)
        @Column(name = "physical_address")
        private String physicalAddress;
        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, max = 30)
        @Column(name = "company_name")
        private String companyName;
        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, max = 30)
        @Column(name = "service_offered")
        private String serviceOffered;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Size(min = 1, max = 20)
        @Column(name = "license_status")
        private String licenseStatus;
        @Basic(optional = false)   
        @Lob
        @Column(name = "memorandum_of_association")
        private byte[] memorandumOfAssociation;
        @Basic(optional = false)

        @Lob
        @Column(name = "articles_of_association")
        private byte[] articlesOfAssociation;
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @Lob
        @Column(name = "certificate_of_incorporation")
        private byte[] certificateOfIncorporation;
        @Basic(optional = false)

        @Lob
        @Column(name = "financial_statement")
        private byte[] financialStatement;

        public Client() {
        }

        public Client(String emailAddress) {
            this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
        }

        public Client(String emailAddress, String licenseStatus, byte[] memorandumOfAssociation, byte[] certificateOfIncorporation) {
            this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
            this.licenseStatus = licenseStatus;
            this.memorandumOfAssociation = memorandumOfAssociation;
            this.certificateOfIncorporation = certificateOfIncorporation;
        }

        public Client(String emailAddress, Integer phoneNumber, String physicalAddress, String companyName, String serviceOffered, String licenseStatus, byte[] memorandumOfAssociation, byte[] articlesOfAssociation, byte[] certificateOfIncorporation, byte[] financialStatement) {
            this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
            this.physicalAddress = physicalAddress;
            this.companyName = companyName;
            this.serviceOffered = serviceOffered;
            this.licenseStatus = licenseStatus;
            this.memorandumOfAssociation = memorandumOfAssociation;
            this.articlesOfAssociation = articlesOfAssociation;
            this.certificateOfIncorporation = certificateOfIncorporation;
            this.financialStatement = financialStatement;
        }



        public String getEmailAddress() {
            return emailAddress;
        }

        public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
            this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
        }

        public Integer getPhoneNumber() {
            return phoneNumber;
        }

        public void setPhoneNumber(Integer phoneNumber) {
            this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        }

        public String getPhysicalAddress() {
            return physicalAddress;
        }

        public void setPhysicalAddress(String physicalAddress) {
            this.physicalAddress = physicalAddress;
        }

        public String getCompanyName() {
            return companyName;
        }

        public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
            this.companyName = companyName;
        }

        public String getServiceOffered() {
            return serviceOffered;
        }

        public void setServiceOffered(String serviceOffered) {
            this.serviceOffered = serviceOffered;
        }

        public String getLicenseStatus() {
            return licenseStatus;
        }

        public void setLicenseStatus(String licenseStatus) {
            this.licenseStatus = licenseStatus;
        }

        public byte[] getMemorandumOfAssociation() {

            return memorandumOfAssociation;
        }

        public void setMemorandumOfAssociation(byte[] memorandumOfAssociation) {
            this.memorandumOfAssociation = memorandumOfAssociation;
        }

        public byte[] getArticlesOfAssociation() {
            return articlesOfAssociation;
        }

        public void setArticlesOfAssociation(byte[] articlesOfAssociation) {
            this.articlesOfAssociation = articlesOfAssociation;
        }

        public byte[] getCertificateOfIncorporation() {
            return certificateOfIncorporation;
        }

        public void setCertificateOfIncorporation(byte[] certificateOfIncorporation)     {
            this.certificateOfIncorporation = certificateOfIncorporation;
        }

        public byte[] getFinancialStatement() {
            return financialStatement;
        }

        public void setFinancialStatement(byte[] financialStatement) {
            this.financialStatement = financialStatement;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 0;
            hash += (emailAddress != null ? emailAddress.hashCode() : 0);
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object object) {

            if (!(object instanceof Client)) {
                return false;
            }
            Client other = (Client) object;
            return !((this.emailAddress == null && other.emailAddress != null) || (this.emailAddress != null && !this.emailAddress.equals(other.emailAddress)));
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "entity.Client[ emailAddress=" + emailAddress + " ]";
        }

    }
```

Here is the Managed Bean

```
    package managed;

    import entity.Client;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.annotation.Resource;
    import javax.ejb.EJB;
    import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
    import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
    import session.ClientFacade;
    import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;

    /**
     *
     * @author rue
     */
    @ManagedBean
    @RequestScoped
    public class ClientController {

        @EJB
        private ClientFacade clientFacade;
        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "potronlinePU")
        private EntityManager em;
        @Resource
        private javax.transaction.UserTransaction utx;

        private Client c;   
        private Client c1;  
        private UploadedFile financialStatementFile;
        private UploadedFile certificateOfIncorporationFile;
        private UploadedFile memorandumOfAssociationFile;
        private UploadedFile articlesOfAssociationFile;

        public ClientController() {
            c = new Client();
            c1 = new Client();
        }

        public void createClient() {
            Client client = new Client(c.getEmailAddress(), c.getPhoneNumber(), c.getPhysicalAddress(), c.getCompanyName(),
                    c.getServiceOffered(), c.getLicenseStatus(), c.getMemorandumOfAssociation(), c.getArticlesOfAssociation(),
                    c.getCertificateOfIncorporation(), c.getFinancialStatement());
            //clientFacade.create(client);

            this.persist(client);
        }

        public UploadedFile getFinancialStatementFile() {
            return financialStatementFile;
        }

        public void setFinancialStatementFile(UploadedFile financialStatementFile) {
            this.financialStatementFile = financialStatementFile;

    //        this.file = file;
            FileInputStream fin;
            if (financialStatementFile != null) {
                try {
                    fin = new FileInputStream(this.financialStatementFile.getContentType());
                    int bytesAvailable = fin.available();
                    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                    fin.read(fileBytes);
                    //acReq.setAcquitedFile(fileBytes);
                    c1.setFinancialStatement(fileBytes);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ClientController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Failed!", financialStatementFile.getFileName() + " is not uploaded.");
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
                }
            } else {
                FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Please select image!!");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
            }
        }

        public UploadedFile getCertificateOfIncorporationFile() {
            return certificateOfIncorporationFile;
        }

        public void setCertificateOfIncorporationFile(UploadedFile certificateOfIncorporationFile) {
            this.certificateOfIncorporationFile = certificateOfIncorporationFile;

            FileInputStream fin;
            if (certificateOfIncorporationFile != null) {
                try {

                    fin = new FileInputStream(this.certificateOfIncorporationFile.getContentType());
                    int bytesAvailable = fin.available();
                    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                    fin.read(fileBytes);
                    c1.setCertificateOfIncorporation(fileBytes);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ClientController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ClientController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            } else {
                FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Please select image!!");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
            }
        }

        public UploadedFile getMemorandumOfAssociationFile() {
            return memorandumOfAssociationFile;
        }

        public void setMemorandumOfAssociationFile(UploadedFile memorandumOfAssociationFile) {
            this.memorandumOfAssociationFile = memorandumOfAssociationFile;

            FileInputStream fin;
            if (memorandumOfAssociationFile != null) {
                try {
                    fin = new FileInputStream(this.memorandumOfAssociationFile.getContentType());
                    int bytesAvailable = fin.available();
                    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                    fin.read(fileBytes);                
                    c1.setMemorandumOfAssociation(fileBytes);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ClientController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Failed!", memorandumOfAssociationFile.getFileName() + " is not uploaded.");
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
                }
            } else {
                FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Please select image!!");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
            }
        }

        public UploadedFile getArticlesOfAssociationFile() {
            return articlesOfAssociationFile;
        }

        public void setArticlesOfAssociationFile(UploadedFile articlesOfAssociationFile) {
            this.articlesOfAssociationFile = articlesOfAssociationFile;

            FileInputStream fin;
            if (articlesOfAssociationFile != null) {
                try {
                    fin = new FileInputStream(this.articlesOfAssociationFile.getContentType());
                    int bytesAvailable = fin.available();
                    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                    fin.read(fileBytes);                
                    c1.setArticlesOfAssociation(fileBytes);

                } catch (IOException ex) {

                    Logger.getLogger(ClientController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Failed!", articlesOfAssociationFile.getFileName() + " is not uploaded.");
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
                }
            } else {
                FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Please select image!!");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
            }
        }

        public Client getC() {
            return c;
        }

        public void setC(Client c) {
            this.c = c;
        }

        public Client getC1() {
            return c1;
        }

        public void setC1(Client c1) {
            this.c1 = c1;
        }

        public void persist(Object object) {
            try {

                utx.begin();
                em.persist(object);
                utx.commit();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "exception caught", e);
                throw new RuntimeException(e);

            }
        }

    }
```

Here is the submitting page

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <body>

        <ui:composition template="./../WEB-INF/clienttemplate.xhtml">

            <ui:define name="top">

            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="content">
                <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" bgcolor="yellow">
                        <p:outputLabel for="compName" value="Compay Name"/>
                        <p:inputText id="compName" value="#{clientController.c.companyName}" />
                        <p:outputLabel for="email" value="Email Address"/>
                        <p:inputText id="email" value="#{clientController.c.emailAddress}" /> 
                        <p:outputLabel for="phone" value="Phone Number"/>
                        <p:inputText id="phone" value="#{clientController.c.phoneNumber}" />
                        <p:outputLabel for="physicalAdd" value="Physical   Address"/>
                        <p:inputText id="physicalAdd" value="#    {clientController.c.physicalAddress}" />
                        <p:outputLabel for="service" value="Service Offered"/>
                        <p:inputText id="service" value="#{clientController.c.serviceOffered}" />
                        <p:outputLabel for="licenseStatus" value="License Status"/>
                        <p:inputText id="licenseStatus" value="#{clientController.c.licenseStatus}" />
                        <p:outputLabel for="memAss" value="Memorandum of Association"/>
                        <p:fileUpload id="memAss" value="#{clientController.memorandumOfAssociationFile}" mode="simple" />
                        <p:outputLabel for="artAss" value="Articles of Association"/>
                        <p:fileUpload id="artAss" value="#{clientController.articlesOfAssociationFile}" mode="simple" />
                        <p:outputLabel for="certInc" value="Certificate of Incorporation"/>
                        <p:fileUpload id="certInc" value="#{clientController.certificateOfIncorporationFile}" mode="simple" />
                        <p:outputLabel for="finSt" value="Financial Statement"/>
                        <p:fileUpload id="finSt" value="#{clientController.financialStatementFile}" mode="simple" />
                        <p:commandButton type="submit" value="Submit" action="#      {clientController.createClient}"  ajax="false" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </h:form>
            </ui:define>

            <ui:define name="bottom">

            </ui:define>

        </ui:composition>

    </body>
</html>





**Here is the web.xml file**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
        <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
            <param-value>Development</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
            <param-value>auto|native|commons</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
            <param-value>aristo</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <filter>
            <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>
                org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
            </filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        </filter-mapping>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>
                30
            </session-timeout>
        </session-config>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

I am using **commons-io-2.4** and **commons-fileupload-1.3** for upload

Can anyone assist, i have been stuck for some days